# If person with specific name exists in People XML list

Tags: c#, linq

How can find out result of this:

```
<People>
<Person name="John" />
<Person name="Andrew" />
</People>
```

I need to find out if person with specific name exists in People list.

Example:

```
if (Element("People").ForAny(person => person.name == "John")) // Returns True
if (Element("People").ForAny(person => person.name == "Amanda")) // Returns False
```

I am using Xml Linq library.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply navigate from the root [element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element?view=netframework-4.8) `People`.
In all its [decendants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=netframework-4.8) `Person`, is there [any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) with the [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute?view=netframework-4.8) `name` is equal to the value you are looking for  :

```
string input = @"<People>
<Person name=""John"" />
<Person name=""Andrew"" />
</People>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var isJohnHere = doc.Element("People")
                    .Descendants("Person")
                    .Any(x=> x.Attribute("name").Value == "John");
```

The same way getting the `List<string>` of people's `name`s will be :

```
var names = doc.Element("People")
                .Descendants("Person")
                .Select(x=> x.Attribute("name").Value);
```

And even shorter " All the `Person`s no matter where there are" :

```
var isJohnHere2 = doc.Descendants("Person")
                     .Any(x=> x.Attribute("name").Value == "John");
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPWhfv)

Comment: What If I have <People> in <rootElement>?

Comment: @JohnDoe, exactly! You start from doc, you have an element named rootElement. Then you do the same : `doc.Element("rootElement").Element("People")`

Comment: OR if you have some hierachy in between but you do not want to navigate one by one . You can directly use Descendants: "In the doc I want all Descendants named 'People'. " => `doc.Descendants("People")` . But thats a list of node and the logic was for only one node? Perhaps you just want the `.First()` then.

Comment: Next time do not forget an [mre], contains the correct data input. This way you will have answer using the correct input, and will not have to adapt. Data can be bogus and still have the correct data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on your separation of concerns: divide your problems into smaller problems that can be used independently. This make it easier to reuse your code for other problems, easier to test your code, make changes without breaking the code.

Your problem consists of two subproblems:

- How to convert XML data to a sequence of Persons
- How to extract Persons with a certain name from a sequence of Persons
- How to detect if a sequence of Persons is not empty?

I don't often convert XML to IEnumerable, but [this answer helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460567/xml-to-ienumerablet)

```
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties
}
```

If in your XML a Person really only has a Name, you don't have to define a special class for it. But then again: are you sure that a Person is nothing more than a Name? Shouldn't that be a collection of Names?

Ok, so we have a Person class (or a string), and we need a function to convert the XML into a sequence of Persons:

Write this as an extension method, so we can let it look like LINQ. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx). The word `this` in the signature makes it an extension method. It allows you to use the method as if it was a method of the string class itself

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> ToPersons(this String xml)
{
    return XElement.Parse(xml)
        .Elements("Person")
        .Select(xmlElement => new Person
        {
            Name = xmlElement.Element("Name").Value,

            // if needed, fill other properties, for instance:
            Id = Int32.Parse(xmlElement.Element("Id").Value),
        });
}
```

Usage:

```
string xmlTxt = ...
IEnumerable<Person> persons = xmlTxt.ToPersons();
```

If you don't have a string with xml, but an XmlReader, consider:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> ToPersons(this XmlReader xmlReader)
{
    while(xmlReader.Read())
    {
        // TODO: read one Person from xmlReader
        Person person = new Person() {...} // you know better how to do this than I
        yield return person
    }
```

Now that we have seperated xml conversion from Person handling, the rest is easy:

**Requirement:**
Given the name of a Person, and some XmlText that represents a sequence of Persons, tell me if a Person with this name is in this sequence

```
string personName = ...
string xmlText = ...      // or Use the XmlReader

bool personAvailable = xmlText.ToPersons()
    .Where(person => person.Name == personName)
    .Any();
```

In words: convert the xmlText to a sequence of Persons. From this sequence keep only those Persons that have a `Name` equal to `personName`. Return true if there is any element left in the remaining sequence.

If you use peculiar characters, or want to ignore case. Consider:

```
IEqualityComparer<strong> personNameComparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
bool personAvailable = xmlText.ToPersons()
    .Where(person => personNameComparer.Equals(person.Name, personName))
    .Any();
```

The nice thing is, because you separated your concerns, you can use `ToPersons` also for other functions:

**Requirement**: give me all New York City Residents, born before 1960

```
var oldPersons = xmlText.ToPersons
    .Where(person => person.Location == "New York City" && person.Birthday.Year < 1960);
```

Or if you get your Persons from a Json file, or a CSV-file,  or a database, you can still get all all New York City Residents, born before 1960, while only writing a new `ToPersons` method.